# How to set animation state to finish

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animations

I've created a slider animation as demonstrated below:

```css
@mixin progress {
  @-webkit-keyframes interval {
    from {
      width: 0;
    }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  animation: var(--duration) linear 0s interval;
  animation-play-state: var(--playState);
}
 .slider-item {
   @include progress;
 }
```

When a click event fires my task is to make the current slider animation be completed.
I have tried to select the target element for example:

```js
this.$refs[`slider-item-${id}`]
```

Nevertheless, the animation property is still empty, is there something that i'm missing here? or is there a better alternative for that? (i have tried the API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate without success)

Comment: can you attach a work codepen or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
animation: var(--duration) linear 0s interval;
```

with

```
animation: var(--duration) linear 10ms forwards;
```

to see the animation end as the last state remaining on your page.